# Application Customiser doesn't work on SharePoint homepage 2019 on-prem

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, sharepoint-framework

I have a very basic application customiser that adds a custom css file to the page, hiding certain elements like the "Get the mobile app" button. The app is installed in the mysite host app catalog, and has been added to the mysite host site collection and runs fine on all pages in the site collection, however it does no run on the SharePoint homepage:

https://my-domain/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx

Is this expected behaviour, and if so what is an alternate approach to customising the SharePoint homepage?

Comment: As per my understanding, App customizer will work on modern site pages only and `https://my-domain/_layouts/15/sharepoint.aspx` is a application page. So, it will not work on this page.

Answer (score 1):

As [Ganesh Sanap](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/69998/ganesh-sanap) mentioned in the comment, `sharepoint.aspx` is an application page in SharePoint 2019, which is known as non-editable and should not be deleted. That is why SPFx Application Customizer does not work for this page.

As far as I know, the only option would be to create a custom application page instead of modifying the default one.

Reference:
[Create application pages for SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/creating-application-pages-for-sharepoint?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Yeah I wasn't planning to modify this file, but I would have thought allowing us to modify or configure it, particularly on prem would be a no-brainer. The ability to at least hide elements like the "Get the mobile app" button are kind of essential in a corporate environment.

Comment: @GeoffBailey It is currently not supported to hide/remove the “Get the mobile app”. There already are requests raised in the SharePoint UserVoice forum: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/31861546-remove-get-the-mobile-app-and-feedback-buttons

Comment: Thanks @Chelsea_MSFT, I was sort of aware of that, but I thought it would be possible to customise the SharePoint homepage with an application customiser. It seems like that's actually not possible at all though. Correct me if I'm wrong please anyone